# CSS Spacing in Multiline Divs

Tags: css, alignment

I'm trying to figure out why I'm having spacing issues when I tile a series of divs within a parent div.  Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SNSvU/4/.  And here's what I have:

HTML

```
<div id="prioritiesWrapper">
<div class="priority"><div class="img">Img here</div><div class="title">This is my priority title</div></div>
<div class="priority"><div class="img">Img here</div><div class="title">This is my priority title; it's longer than the others and wraps</div></div>
<div class="priority"><div class="img">Img here</div><div class="title">This is my priority title</div></div>
<div class="priority"><div class="img">Img here</div><div class="title">This is my priority title</div></div>
<div class="priority"><div class="img">Img here</div><div class="title">This is my priority title; it's longer than the others and wraps</div></div>
<div class="priority"><div class="img">Img here</div><div class="title">This is my priority title; it's longer than the others and wraps</div></div>
<div class="priority"><div class="img">Img here</div><div class="title">This is my priority title</div></div>
<div class="priority"><div class="img">Img here</div><div class="title">This is my priority title</div></div>
<div class="priority"><div class="img">Img here</div><div class="title">This is my priority title</div></div>
<div class="priority"><div class="img">Img here</div><div class="title">This is my priority title</div></div>
```

CSS

```
#prioritiesWrapper {
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#prioritiesWrapper .priority .img {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

#prioritiesWrapper .priority .title {
    margin: auto 0;
}

#prioritiesWrapper div.priority {
    width: 350px;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

Spacing seems to be just fine between divs as long as the priority titles on a given row are all similar (one line or two lines), but if they differ, it throws the other div off alignment.

How do I get a uniform spacing between divs regardless of lines of content?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems I was a bit hasty in posting this-- adding vertical-align: middle to the div.priority rule did the trick.  I'm starting to understand when this rule works and when it doesn't but I still have a little way to go.

Comment: Sorry, Patsy-- I think I may have thrown in the rule that fixed it just before you looked at the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/SNSvU/5/

```
#prioritiesWrapper div.priority
{
width: 600px;
height: 80px;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px 30px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: black;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 2em;
}
```

Or do you want it to be more dynamic like this? http://jsfiddle.net/SNSvU/6/

```
#prioritiesWrapper div.priority
{
width: auto;
height: 80px;
display: block;
margin: 10px 30px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: black;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This css working DEMO **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/aEDGf/1/)**

```
#prioritiesWrapper div.priority {
width: 350px;
height: 80px;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px 30px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: black;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 2em;
vertical-align: middle;/* ADDED */
}
```

Comment: Thanks-- I found the vertical align culprit not long after posting.  I love this community!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about the height of the divs then change the height property to auto... like this

```
#prioritiesWrapper div.priority
{
width: 350px;
height: auto;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px 30px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: black;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 2em;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SNSvU/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/SNSvU/11/ . Give `#prioritiesWrapper` `overflow:hidden` and `#prioritiesWrapper div.priority` `float:left`. I guess thats it.